# Creating new Functions with Linear Regression in R :

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I'm having a trouble when creating a function that calls the `lm()` function:

```
regresionLineal <- function (vardep, varindep1, varindep2, DATA) {
  lm(vardep ~ varindep1 + varindep2, data = DATA)
  }
```

Then I call it using data from a data frame I created previously (`DATOS`)...

```
regresionLineal(Estatura, Largo, Ancho, DATOS)
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Estatura' not found
>   Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)

Any help will be welcome...

Comment: Since the formula interface uses unquoted names, you would need to pass them as such, which is, frankly, complicated. (Right now R thinks you're trying to pass objects the [column] names refer to, which don't actually exist outside of the data.frame.) It's actually easier to pass a whole formula as a parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should do:

```
regresionLineal <- function (vardep, varindep1, varindep2, DATA) {
  lm(paste(vardep, "~", varindep1, "+", varindep2), data = DATA)
  }
```

where you pass in `vardep`, `varindep1`, `varindep2` as strings. As an example, I use R's built-in `trees` dataset:

```
regresionLineal("Height", "Girth", "Volumn", trees)
# Call:
# lm(formula = paste(vardep, "~", varindep1, "+", varindep2), data = DATA)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)        Girth       Volume  
#     83.2958      -1.8615       0.5756
```

However, I don't see why we bother doing this. If we have to specify every variable in the formula, why not simply pass in a complete formula? And in that case, you can use `lm()` directly without define your own function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Well, I fogtot to say that I also have to call another functions on my formula, That's Why I did this. Anyway 'lm' was the harder one.

Comment: Super easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also, you may already know this, but it might be helpful to keep in mind that the regression object created here won't exist outside of the function unless assigned to the global environment or whatever environment you're working in. If you need to call the reg. object outside of this function later for some reason you should assign it as: `model1 <<-  lm(paste(vardep, "~", varindep1, "+", varindep2), data = DATA)` to be able to call from the global env.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a model with an arbitrary number of independent variables, you can use the below:

```r
create_lm <- function(data, dep, covs) {
# Create the first part of the formula with the dependent variable
  form_base <- paste(dep, "~")
# Create a string that concatenates your covs vector with a "+" between each variable
  form_vars <- paste(covs, collapse = " + ")
# Paste the two parts together
  formula <- paste(form_base, form_vars)
# Call the lm function on your formula
  lm(formula, data = data)
}
```

For instance, using the built-in mtcars dataset:

```r
create_lm(mtcars, "mpg", c("wt", "cyl"))

Call:
lm(formula = formula, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt          cyl  
     39.686       -3.191       -1.508
```

The downside is that the printed output from the model doesn't reflect the particular call you made to lm, not sure if there is any way around this.

Comment: there is, please look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd add to this for any future reader.

The solution I came up with (which is not perfect) is the following function:

```r
f <- function(y, x1, x2, df) {
  cmd = paste0("lm(", y, " ~ ", x1, " + ", x2, ", data = ",  deparse1(substitute(df)), ")")
  eval(parse(text = cmd))
}
```

By doing this you can call, for example,

```r
R> f("mpg", "hp", "wt", mtcars)
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ hp + wt, data = mtcars)
Coefficients:
(Intercept)           hp           wt  
    37.2273      -0.0318      -3.8778
```

The main advantage over other approaches is that the output of the `lm` does not obfuscate names of variable or the dataframe.

Perhaps future readers can appreciate that running this command requires knowledge of R base functions: `parse`, `deparse1`, `substitute` and `eval`

Thanks!